# TimerTask completion doesn't couse Task.any to yield completed task

Tags: javascript, azure-durable-functions

Recently I have started learning Azure serverless computing.

While investigating durable functions I bump into a problem with TimeTasks.

Here are some examples to explain a problem:

1) [code snippet from learning path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-long-running-serverless-workflow-with-durable-functions/6-exercise-add-a-durable-timer-to-manage-a-long-running-task)

```js
module.exports = df.orchestrator(function* (context) {
    const outputs = [];
    const deadline = moment.utc(context.df.currentUtcDateTime).add(20, "s");
    const activityTask = context.df.waitForExternalEvent("Approval");
    const timeoutTask = context.df.createTimer(deadline.toDate());

    const winner = yield context.df.Task.any([activityTask, timeoutTask]);
    if (winner === activityTask) {
        outputs.push(yield context.df.callActivity("Approval", "Approved"));
    }
    else
    {
        outputs.push(yield context.df.callActivity("Escalation", "Head of department"));
    }

    if (!timeoutTask.isCompleted) {
        // All pending timers must be complete or canceled before the function exits.
        timeoutTask.cancel();
    }

    return outputs;
});
```

2) [code snippet from docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-external-events?tabs=javascript)

```js
const df = require("durable-functions");

module.exports = df.orchestrator(function*(context) {
    const event1 = context.df.waitForExternalEvent("Event1");
    const event2 = context.df.waitForExternalEvent("Event2");
    const event3 = context.df.waitForExternalEvent("Event3");

    const winner = yield context.df.Task.any([event1, event2, event3]);
    if (winner === event1) {
        // ...
    } else if (winner === event2) {
        // ...
    } else if (winner === event3) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

As for the second example the situation is super clear:

1. we make HTTP call to endpoint which is cousing orchestrator to be fired,
2. orchestrator's generator function collects 3 different `Task` objects, each of which is waiting for an external POST API call (either with **Event1**, **Event2** or **Event3** payload),
3. we are `yield`ing `TaskSet`'s output which is a first of any completed task in the given array of tasks - once we submit any of those 3 events, we get the winner and code continues.

At least this is how I understand it. We start with 3 pending tasks and `taskSet` also pending:
[debugger info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSRjX.png). Once any of this events is rised, some task change its state to completed, `taskSet` change its state to completed, result is returned.

Now let just replace on of those tasks with tim based task like so:

```js
const df = require("durable-functions");
const moment = require("moment");

module.exports = df.orchestrator(function*(context) {
    const event1 = context.df.waitForExternalEvent("Event1");
    const event2 = context.df.waitForExternalEvent("Event2");
    // const event3 = context.df.waitForExternalEvent("Event3");
    const deadline = moment.utc(context.df.currentUtcDateTime).add(10, "s");
    const event3 = context.df.createTimer(deadline.toDate());

    const taskSet = context.df.Task.any([event1, event2, event3]);
    const winner = yield taskSet;
    if (winner === event1) {
        // ...
    } else if (winner === event2) {
        // ...
    } else if (winner === event3) {
        // ...
        timeoutTask.cancel();
    }
});
```

Now the idea is also simple: either we failed to pass **Event1** or **Event2** and timeout is rised (**Event3**) or we did. But the problem is that even if **Event3** gets completed after 10s we cannot assign the result - it is undefined: [debugger info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1mT5.png). Although we CAN yield (after 10 seconds debugger starts to go through entire finction ones more so `yield` was triggered but trying to step through its assignment couses debugger to wait for another task to complete). It seems like timeTask gets completed but `Task.any` failed to notice that.

Does anybody have any suggestions why this is not working? The example in (1) should work as documentation suggests but it doesn't (due to the same issue - timeout is never triggered).